# Data aggregation in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using Apache nifi to process the data from different resources and I have independent pipelines created for each data flow. I want to combine this data to process further. Is there any way I can aggregate the data and write it to a single file. The data is present in the form of flowfiles attributes in Nifi.

Comment: Can you describe a bit more?  Examples of the separate data, and what the merged data should look would might be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the [`MergeContent`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html) processor, which accepts configuration values for min/max batch size, etc. and combines a number of flowfiles into a single flowfile according to the provided merge strategy.